# How to detect if the excel file is in read-only mode and exit out?

Tags: excel, powershell

I am having trouble detecting if an excel file is in read only mode. I know there is a workbook.open method which has a read me attribute but is there a way to have that where if it knows that file is read only and exit? I did try adding .readonly to the variable file at the end to see if that would work.

This is what I have so far.

```bash
$file = 'path'
$excl = New-Object -ComObject 'Excel.Application'

if ($file.readonly) {
    Exit
}
try {
    $wrkb = $excl.Workbooks.Open($file)
}
Catch {
    Exit
}

$excl.DisplayAlerts = $FALSE

try {
    $wrkb.Save()
}
catch {
    Exit
}
```

Comment: Please clarify - by directly updating your question - if you're looking to find out if a given file has the `ReadOnly` attribute persistently set, or whether you're trying to determine whether a given file is _temporarily_ effectively read-only, due to being _in use_ by someone else.

Comment: Basically if the file has the read-only attribute set

Answer (score 2):

I presume what you're looking for is testing if the [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-8.0) instance has the [`ReadOnly` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=net-8.0):

```bash
$file = 'path'

# Can also do it thru:
# .Attributes.HasFlag([System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly)
if ((Get-Item $file).IsReadOnly) {
    return
}
try {
    $excl = New-Object -ComObject 'Excel.Application'
    $wrkb = $excl.Workbooks.Open($file)
    $excl.DisplayAlerts = $FALSE
    $wrkb.Save()
}
catch {
    # handling
}
finally {
    if ($excl) {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excl)
    }
}
```