# How to capture the error message of an excel display alert in powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to capture the message of an excel display alert if it pops up in excel. So for example, if a message from excel shows up saying file is locked for editing, it would write that error in command prompt.

I am trying to capture it in a try catch statement but it only captures the errors from the command prompt not from the actual excel display alert.

```
$file = 'path'

$excl = New-Object -ComObject 'Excel.Application'

if
 ($file.readonly) {

    Exit
}
try 
{
    $wrkb = $excl.Workbooks.Open($file)
}

Catch 
{
    write-output Get-Error 
}

$excl.DisplayAlerts = $TRUE

try 
{
    $wrkb.Save()
}
catch
 {
    write-output Get-Error 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Preface**:

- In a comment on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78004866/45375) of yours, you were asked:

  - > [are you] looking to find out if a given file has the `ReadOnly` attribute persistently set, or whether you're trying to determine whether a given file is temporarily effectively read-only, due to *being in use by someone else*.
  - And you responded:

    - > Basically if the file has the read-only attribute set
  - Your current question suggests that you were looking for the former, not the latter, after all.
- In a [later question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78044907/45375), you asked about making Excel - along with any messages / alerts it might display - *visible in the foreground*.

  - You were pointed to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78048290/45375).
  - However, unlike the Excel window itself, *alerts* normally *automatically* show in the foreground, though they may not have the input focus.

---

The following is based on the Excel version that comes with Microsoft Office 2019.

- Excel responding to a file being *in use by another user* when `.Workbooks.Open()` is called does *not* cause an alert - Excel simply quietly opens the file in *read-only mode* and proceeds.
- On calling `.Save()` on such a read-only workbook later, you *will* get an alert - in the form of a GUI *message box* - *unless* you've explicitly set `.DisplayAlerts = $false` on the Excel object.

  - With `.DisplayAlerts = $true` (the default) in effect, you:

    - can *not* prevent display of the message box
    - you *can* catch an implied error condition, but *only* if you click `No` or `Cancel` - not also when clicking `Yes` (see next major bullet point).

      - In a [`try` / `catch` / `finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement, the (terminating) error at hand is reflected in the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_); the [`Get-Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-error) cmdlet, available in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), outputs details about the most recent error with friendly formatting to the success output stream and therefore by default to the display.
      - Therefore, use `Get-Error` *alone* in the `catch` block to produce such output; by contrast, `Write-Output Get-Error` outputs *verbatim* `Get-Error`, because you need `(...)` to enclose *commands an expressions* in order to use them as *arguments*. The - redundant - equivalent of `Get-Error` alone would therefore be `Write-Output (Get-Error)`. To simply *re-throw* the error at hand, in the form of a *script*-terminating (fatal) error, use `throw` in isolation (you needn't even refer to `$_` in that case).
  - With `.DisplayAlerts = $false` in effect or when clicking `Yes` in the message box, an attempt to save the effectively locked file *is quietly ignored*, i.e. any changes are *not* saved.
- Therefore, **your best bet is to detect up front whether a just-opened workbook is read-only, and throw an error then**:

  - A workbook object's `.ReadOnly` property indicates `$true` both when the workbook is *effectively, temporarily* read-only due to *being used by another process* as well as when the workbook file is *persistently* read-only due its `ReadOnly` *file-system attribute* being set.
    For brevity, the code below doesn't distinguish these two cases, but `(Get-Item -LiteralPath $file).IsReadOnly` returning `$true` implies the latter condition.

```bash
& { # Execute in a child scope, to ensure that COM objects are released.

  # Specify the target workbook path.
  # Adjust as needed - be sure to use a FULL path.
  $file = "$PWD\book1.xlsx"
  
  try {
    $excl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $wrkb = $excl.Workbooks.Open($file)
    # Throw an error, if the workbook is read-only.
    if ($wrkb.ReadOnly) { throw "Workbook '$file' is read-only, possibly because it is being used by another process." }
    # ... modify the workbok as needed
    # Sample modification: insert a new worksheet at the start.
    $newWs = $wrkb.Worksheets.Add()
    # ... then save.
    $wrkb.Save()
  }
  catch {
    throw # Relay any error, as a fatal one.
  }
  finally {
    # Make sure that Excel quits, so that its process eventually terminates.
    if ($excl) { $excl.Quit() }
  }
}
```

Comment: So there isn't really a way to capture the display alert message ?

Comment: @jjkhjiuu: Not that I'm aware of. But you don't need that, as demonstrated by this answer.